# Class of a sequence of numbers

Tags: r

I can create a sequence of numbers in one of three ways:

```
> 1:4
[1] 1 2 3 4

> seq(1,4)
[1] 1 2 3 4

> c(1,2,3,4)
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

But why does `c()` return a different class?

```
> class(1:4)       
[1] "integer"

> class(seq(1,4))
[1] "integer"

> class(c(1,2,3,4))
[1] "numeric"
```

EDIT: added `seq()` to the discussion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Value section of `help(":")` tells what the colon operator returns.  It says:

> ... will be of type integer if from is integer-valued and the result is representable in the R integer type.

So, if `from` can be represented as an integer, the whole vector is coerced to integer

```
> class(1.0:3.1)
[1] "integer"
> 1.0:3.1
[1] 1 2 3
```

Generally in R, `1` is `numeric`.  If you want an `integer`, you have to append an `L`

```
> class(1)
[1] "numeric"
> class(1L)
[1] "integer"
```

Furthermore, `c` will coerce all arguments "to a common type which is the type of the returned value" (from `?c`).  What type that is "is determined from the highest type of the components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list < expression."

So, if any argument to `c` is more general than `integer`, the whole vector will be coerced to the more general class.

```
> class(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L))
[1] "integer"
> class(c(1L, 2, 3L, 4L)) # 2 is numeric, so the whole vector is coerced to numeric
[1] "numeric"
> class(c(1L, 2, "3L", 4L)) # "3L" is character, so the whole vector is coerced to character
[1] "character"
```

---

Re: the `seq` case,

`seq(1, 4)` is identical to `1:4` as stated in `?seq`

seq(from, to) "generates the sequence from, from+/-1, ..., to (identical to from:to)"

Comment: +1, deleting my half-formed response. Might be worth noting why `c` is working the way it is...

Comment: So `integer-valued` clearly doesn't mean an `integer` `class` for the 'from' value... `class(1:4)` is from a `numeric` to a `numeric` but returns an `integer`, because the `1` can be interpreted as an `integer`, even though it isn't formally. That is confusing.

Comment: The part about class(1:4) doesn't make sense. 1, 2, 3, and 4 are numerics since I didn't specify 1L, 2L, 3L, and 4L, which are integers. Then why do class(1:4) and class(1L:4L) both return "integer"?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 The `:` operator coerces the whole vector to `integer` if it is possible to represent the number that comes before the `:` as an integer even if you _didn't_ represent it that way on input (if that helps... I agree it's confusing)

Comment: Added "seq()" function to my question.

Comment: This is an old thread but why does `seq(1,10,2)` return a numeric then? Is this because it doesn't default to 1:10, and thus creates a numeric vector as `c(1,3,5,7,9)`? Would I need to coerce this as well?