# difference between 1:10 and c(1:10)

Tags: r, rstudio

I understand that c is used to combine elements. But what is the difference between 1:10 and c(1:10)? I see that the outputs are the same. Shouldn't c(1:10) give an error, because 1:10 already combines all the elements?

```
> 1:10
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> c(1:10)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> class(1:10)
[1] "integer"
> class(c(1:10))
[1] "integer"
```

Comment: `c` is used to concatenate not combine.

Comment: No, `c` can be used to *concatenate* any number of elements or objects, including 1. See the help file `?c`; specifically the argument `...`.

Comment: @LyzandeR and @nrussell, the official documentation disagrees, or at least, does not make a meaningful distinction between the terms concatenate and combine. The title of the help page and the description say that it combines elements, and the text for the argument `...` says that those are the objects to be concatenated. By the help titles, `cat` is the function that does concatenation.

Comment: and `paste` for concatenation too...

Comment: @Aaron I saw the official documentation before posting the comment. I really prefer the word concatenate to the word combine and yes although there is no clear distinction between the two in the documentation, I feel that the word combine is used to denote that the concatenated string is 'combined' into a vector. Hard to say what the author had in mind exactly. The word concatenate is used in most cases in SO anyway and I feel that it describes the function better. Combine is also a separate function in R (in randomForest).

Comment: Fair enough; I can certainly see where you're coming from. I personally try to avoid concatenate, both because it's a technical word and because of potential confusion between whether string or vector concatenation is meant. I prefer using the ordinary words combine and paste. Especially given the documentation, I suggest also that simply pointing to a potential difference in meaning between concatenate and combine without explaining the difference is not terribly helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that is a valid point.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049057/class-of-a-sequence-of-numbers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you combine (aka `c` function) with only one parameter it is the same as the identity (aka not calling the `c` function). Therefore `c(1:10)` is the same as `1:10`. However you can combine with as many arguments as you want with different type (character,number...). It will convert the type for you.

```
 all.equal(1:10,c(1:5,6:10))

[1] TRUE

all.equal("meow",c("meow"))

[1] TRUE

c(1:5,6:10,"meow")

[1] "1"    "2"    "3"    "4"    "5"    "6"    "7"    "8"    "9"    "10"   "meow" 

class(c(1:5,6:10,"meow"))

[1] "character"
```

Another difference is that you can call c with the parameter recursive. As the doc states:

```
?c

Usage

c(..., recursive = FALSE)
Arguments

... 
objects to be concatenated.

recursive   
logical. If recursive = TRUE, the function recursively descends through lists (and pairlists) combining all their elements into a vector.
```

Comment: Nice answer, though in the documentation for `c`, combine and concatenate seem to be used similarly. Following the titles of the help pages, I think of `c` as combine, in that it combines together vectors into a longer vector, and `paste` (and also `cat`) as concatenate, as it concatenates multiple character strings into one (or a vector, if used in a vectorized way).